# TypeScript, JavaScript how to access lambda variable

Tags: javascript, lambda, typescript

```
interface users {
    s:number;
    b:string;
}

function getPropertyName(propertyFunction: (a:users) => any) {
    console.log(propertyFunction.toString()); // ii => ii.s > x && ii.s < 3
    // how to read x variable here ?
}

(function() {
    var x = 4;
    getPropertyName(ii => ii.s > x && ii.s < 3);
})();
```

How i can access to variable x in getPropertyName function??

Comment: there's no way to do that. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: You have to have `x` and `getPropertyName` in the same scope.. different scopes, no way to access.  That or modify `getPropertyName`, so it can take an extra argument.

Comment: i want write ORM :)
and that would like where function arguments...

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on what Jeremy Starcher said in the form of a code answer.. Change to your needs:

```
function test(func: (x:any, ii:any)=> any){
    //do extra stuff here
}

var x, ii;
test(function (x, ii) {
    //do stuff here
});
```